# Powershell: Special characters in xml using foreach-object can't produce match

Tags: xml, powershell

I am beginner and found a script on this webpage that does what I was after but when there are special characters `*` and `'` powershell can't produce match and column2 of my CSV file doesn't get added to the XML file.

This is the script

```
$c = Import-Csv C:\temp\testlinks.csv
Get-ChildItem C:\temp\output.xml | Foreach-Object {
  # Out-String in the next line lets you work with a single string rather than an
  # array of strings.
  $xmldoc = (Get-Content $_.PSPath | Out-String)

  # Loop through your CSV, updating $xmldoc with each pass
  $c | Foreach-Object {
    $xmldoc = $xmldoc -replace $_.column1name, ($_.column1name + " " + $_.column2name)
  }

  # Write the updated $xmldoc back to the original XML file's path
  $xmldoc | Set-Content $_.PSPath
}
```

This is what my CSV file has in column1 and my XML file has:

```
<title lang="en">M*A*S*H</title>
<title lang="en">Who&apos;s The Boss?</title>
```

Thank you

Comment: `-replace` supports regex. Theoretically your strings have regex meta characters that need to be escaped. Use `.Replace()` instead  (since you are not using regex anyway) or escape them first with `[regex]::Escape()`

Comment: Thank you that worked perfectly

Answer (score 2):

`-replace` uses regex for the pattern, so you need to escape special characters. Try:

```
$xmldoc = $xmldoc -replace ([regex]::Escape($_.column1name)), ($_.column1name + " " + $_.column2name)
```